# “spend money -ing” or “spend money to”

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I learned that verb **spend** followed by **time** or **money** usually go along with **-ing** form (with or without preposition *on or in*).

However, I found a sentence in TOEFL:

> *The university should spend money **to** support activities where student can socialize with.*

Now I am confused!

Is there any constraint with regard to **spend money/time** which I do not know?

Answer (score 1):

The general phrase is:

> a person spends money on something or someone

Almost any preposition can go after **to spend (adjective) money (on something or someone)**.

- I spend money **before** I have it.
- The mayor spends money **at** the tabacco store.
- My girlfriend loves to spend my money on dresses **behind** my back.
- We are spending lots of money on blackjack **with** our poker chips.
- Paul wants to spend his money on his wife **in order to** make her happy.
- Paul does want to spend money on jewelry **for** his wife **to** make her more happy.